# How to append system time to the file name in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I am very new to oracle.I need to create a file with the system timestamp from oracle. Please let me know how do  i do that.

More over I need to write any exceptions or errors thrown by my pl/sql code to a file and exit after an error. How do i do this?

Thanks,
Priya.R

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to look into the [UTL_FILE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#BABGGEDF) Oracle supplied package, as you're trying to use PL/SQL to create the file.

You can generate the file this way:

(You'll need to create an Oracle DIRECTORY first, pointing to the OS location of the file:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DIR AS 'your OS directory';
```

Note that the name 'DIR' is used in the sample code that follows. You will also require the CREATE DIRECTORY privilege, and then grant read and write permissions on the directory to the user who will use it:

```
GRANT READ,WRITE ON DIR TO user1;
```

)

```
DECLARE
  v_logfile VARCHAR2(100);
  v_FH      UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  v_logfile := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS')||'_process.log';
  v_FH      := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(DIR, v_logfile, 'w');
  UTL_FILE.PUTLINE(v_FH, 'Some text on a new line');
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_FH);
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can get a dynamic filename in SQL Plus

```
SET TERMOUT OFF

DEFINE dynamic_filename = idle
COLUMN which_dynamic NEW_VALUE dynamic_filename

SELECT   'prefix_'
       ||TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD' )
       ||'_'
       ||TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'HH24MISS' )
       ||'.log'   which_dynamic
  FROM dual;

SET TERMOUT ON

SPOOL &dynamic_filename

SELECT * FROM dual;

SPOOL OFF
```

The file gets created in the default directory for SQL Plus (on windows this is the "Start In:" property of the shortcut)

To place the output in a known directory amend the SPOOL command to something like...

```
SPOOL c:\output_dir\&dynamic_filename
```

To get an SQL Plus script to exit after an error then include this command...

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE ROLLBACK
```

Comment: OP did state that this was to be done from PL/SQL. This is a SQL*Plus-centric solution that won't work in PL/SQL.

Comment: To DCookie - the OP didn't state the file was to be created from PL/SQL, just "from Oracle". They then stated they wanted to "write any exceptions or errors thrown by my pl/sql code to a file and exit", from this I assumed that the PL/SQL was being run by SQL*Plus so therefore constructed my answer appropriately.

Comment: @Paul, point taken - the question is not perfectly clear. I would argue, however, that "from Oracle" is not the same thing as "from SQL*Plus" (and SQL*Plus was never mentioned), although some fail to see the distinction, as perhaps is the case with the OP.